# How to implement a Box-like `MyBox` that supports trait objects like `Vec<MyBox<dyn MyTrait>>`

Tags: rust, types

The following `MyBox` struct is setup extremely similarly to `Box`, and yet it does not work with a vector of trait objects in the struct `Vec<MyBox<dyn MyTrait>>`. However a vector of trait objects in a `Box` works just fine, `Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>`.

The error is

> expected struct `mybox::MyBox<dyn mybox::MyTrait>`
> found struct `mybox::MyBox<mybox::MyStruct>`

What is it about `Box` that allows it to properly type check? Does `Box` implement a trait that allows it to resolve?

```rust
use std::ptr::NonNull;

trait MyTrait {}

struct MyStruct {}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}

struct MyBox<T: ?Sized> {
    value: NonNull<T>
}

impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> MyBox<T> {
        unsafe {
            MyBox { value: NonNull::new_unchecked(Box::into_raw(Box::new(value))) }
        }
    }
}

/// Works just fine
fn main_box() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = Vec::new();
    let x: Box<MyStruct> = Box::new(MyStruct {});
    v.push(x);
}

/// Has type error
fn main_mybox() {
    let mut v: Vec<MyBox<dyn MyTrait>> = Vec::new();
    let x: MyBox<MyStruct> = MyBox::new(MyStruct {});
    v.push(x);
}
```

I have tried mimicking the structure of `Box<T>` but there must be a trait that it implements that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyStruct` and `dyn MyTrait` are different types, what allows coercion from one to the other for a `Box` is the [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html#impl-CoerceUnsized%3CBox%3CU,+A%3E%3E-for-Box%3CT,+A%3E) implementation of `Box<T, A>` to `Box<U, A>` which you're lacking.

```rust
#![feature(coerce_unsized, unsize)]
use std::marker::Unsize;
use std::ops::CoerceUnsized;
impl<T, U> CoerceUnsized<MyBox<U>> for MyBox<T>
where
    T: Unsize<U> + ?Sized,
    U: ?Sized {}
```

As you can see that requires 2 features to implement at the moment so you have to run a nightly compiler to use it.

If you have to use a stable compiler you could do the coercion on the `Box` and turn that into `MyBox<dyn MyTrait>` afterwards:

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized> From<Box<T>> for MyBox<T> {
    fn from(b: Box<T>) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            MyBox {
                value: NonNull::new_unchecked(Box::into_raw(b)),
            }
        }
    }
}
/// Has type error
fn main_mybox() {
    let mut v: Vec<MyBox<dyn MyTrait>> = Vec::new();
    let b: Box<dyn MyTrait> = Box::new(MyStruct {}); // coercion happens here
    let x: MyBox<dyn MyTrait> = b.into();
    v.push(x);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. In what way is `MyStruct` a different type than `dyn MyTrait`, if it implements `MyTrait`? I'm guessing it's because at runtime it's not the struct itself, but the struct of pointers that resolve via dynamic dispatch?

Comment: In the sense that `MyStruct` items and `dyn MyTrait` items (or boxed versions thereof) can't simply be interchanged. Similar with `struct A;` and `struct B;` while neither has any fields and memory layout / usage of both is the same they're different types and can't be interchanged.